# How to run the code sequentially using Deferred?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, dojo

Inside of this for-loop, I hope to force it to run the AJAX code block first. With the result (i.e. *data.LocationId*), I want to save that on the server, and then run the loop with *i* decreasing.

If you see my console.log, I hope it could be:

> asyncProcess
>
> data.LocationId  7615
>
> asyncProcess
>
> data.LocationId  7614
>
> asyncProcess
>
> data.LocationId  7613

But actually it is:

> asyncProcess
>
> asyncProcess
>
> asyncProcess
>
> data.LocationId  7615
>
> data.LocationId  7614
>
> data.LocationId  7613

How can this be achieved?

This is my code:

```
for (i = projectAreaSet.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    function asyncProcess(geometry)
    {
        console.log("asyncProcess");
        var deferred = new Deferred(); //Dojo, not jQuery

        var locationProfile = { ProjectId: projectId }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(locationProfile),
            url: "api/LocationProfile/Create",
            contentType: "application/json",
        })
        .success(function (data)
        {
            LocationIdSet.push(data.LocationId);
            console.log("data.LocationId ", data.LocationId);
            var currentProjectGraphic = new esri.Graphic(geometry, newSymbol, attributes =
                { "ID": data.LocationId, "Type": 1}, null);
            var currentLayer = that.map.getLayer("Project");
            currentLayer.applyEdits([currentProjectGraphic], null, null);
            deferred.resolve();
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
    var saveProject = asyncProcess(projectAreaSet[i]);
}
```

Comment: What is this code block trying to accomplish?  Do you want to run these ajax calls in parallel or in sequence (each call does not seem to depend on the previous ones so it looks like they could be run in parallel)?  What are you trying to get out of the `for` loop as the result?

Comment: Thanks! Just two purpose: Ajax POST to save the data in database, applyEdits method to save the geometry on ArcGIS Server. I have finished it using the method provided by Sam Onela finally!

Comment: Uhh, you are NOT supposed to edit the chosen solution into your question.  Here on stack overflow, questions should remain questions.  Answers are answers.  You indicate which answer you selected by marking the "best answer" with the green checkmark.  That's how stack overflow is supposed to work.

Comment: Oh! Sorry! It is my first time...

Comment: But is there a place to put the final workable code?

Comment: No, not really.  If your final workable code is substantially different than the answers that were posted, you can post it in your own answer or you can add comments to the selected answer explaining what you did differently.  Both Sam's and my answers show their concepts to anyone who comes later to read this question and the answers.  The specific details of your implementation are particular to your project and probably of no long term interest here as a future teaching tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I support jfriend00's suggestion of running the requests in parallel, you specifically asked:

> How can this be achieved?<sup>[image]</sup>

If you really want them run serially/sequentially, one technique would be to run the next iteration from the *success()* callback.

In the code below, the *for* statement has been removed, and *i* has been made a parameter of the function *asyncProcess()*. Then in the success callback, if the value of *i* is greater than 0, it calls the function again after subtracting one value from *i* (just like the *for* loop did).

```
 var i = projectAreaSet.length - 1;
 asyncProcess(projectAreaSet[i], i);
 function asyncProcess(geometry, i) {
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          //...other options
       })
      .success(function(data) {
           LocationIdSet.push(data.LocationId);
           //instantiate new esri.Graphic, call currentLayer.applyEdits()
           //then run the next iteration, if appropriate
           if (i > 0) {
               asyncProcess(projectAreaSet[i-1], i-1);
           }
           deferred.resolve();
       });
```

See this demonstrated in [this plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/bTUbGUqaqjZezY9iGH7r/).

#### Update:

After reading the discusssion of the answer, it appears you will aim for a parallel approach. For that, since jQuery is being utilized, look at using the [.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) function- passing an array of promises (e.g. Returned by [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax)).

Take a look at [this updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WfE5Vt58d792f8dVXbpM?p=preview). You will notice that the function *asyncProcess* has been updated to return the call to `$.ajax()`, which is a [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) object, which "*implements the Promise interface*"<sup>[1](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jqxhr-object)</sup>.

Using that change, the promises can be added to an array. Then use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) (i.e. `...`) to pass the promises to [$.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/).

```
$.when(...promises).done(function() { ... });
```

The spread operator is added in ES-6 so older browser like IE won't support it. If support is needed for such browsers,  [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) can be used to call [$.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) with those promises.

```
$.when.apply(null, promises).done(function() { ... });
```

In the *.done()* callback of the call to `$.when()`, each argument is an array, where the first element is the data. Putting it all together, we have code like below:

```
var promises = [];
for (i = projectAreaSet.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    promises.push(asyncProcess(projectAreaSet[i], i));
}
$.when(...promises).done(function() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments, function(response) {
      var data = response[0];
      console.log("data.LocationId ", data.LocationId);
      LocationIdSet.push(data.LocationId);
      geometry = projectAreaSet[data.i];
      /* continue with normal code:
      var currentProjectGraphic = new esri.Graphic(geometry, newSymbol, attributes =
            { "ID": data.LocationId, "Type": 1}, null);
      var currentLayer = that.map.getLayer("Project");
        currentLayer.applyEdits([currentProjectGraphic], null, null);*/
    });
});
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Well, actually you asked "***How to make this happen***" in [the original post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42986752/1) but somebody edited your post...</sub>
<sup>1</sup><sub>https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jqxhr-object</sub>

Comment: It is my first ask on Stack Overflow. Thank you so much! It finally works and very easy to understand. I could apply this thought to my other similar tasks!

Comment: Because I am not a native English speaker and not good at presenting my question clearly. Haha~

Comment: Why is the `saveProject` variable there?  It won't have a useful value in it because `asyncProcess()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @jfriend00 I kept the original line intact, in case the OP decided to use that variable later- if this was codereview.stackexchange.com then I would have reported things like cleaning up variables.

Comment: It really returns nothing useful. The two processes inside of loop are what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears that your ajax calls are all independent of one another (one doesn't depend on the other), you can run them all in parallel and use promises to keep the result in order so you can then process the result in order.  This will generally be a faster end-to-end execution time, but will still let you process the results in order.  You can do that using jQuery promises like this:

```
var promises = [];
for (var i = projectAreaSet.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    (function(geometry) {
        promises.push($.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({ProjectId: projectId}),
            url: "api/LocationProfile/Create",
            contentType: "application/json"
        }).then(function(data) {
            // make resolved value be data and geometry together so we can
            // process them in order together later
            return {geometry: geometry, data: data};
        }));
    })(projectAreaSet[i]);
}
$.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
    var results = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    // process results array here in the order they were requested
    results.forEach(function(obj) {
        var data = obj.data;
        var geometry = obj.geometry;
        LocationIdSet.push(data.LocationId);
        console.log("data.LocationId ", data.LocationId);
        var currentProjectGraphic = new esri.Graphic(geometry, newSymbol, attributes = {
            "ID": data.LocationId,
            "Type": 1
        }, null);
        var currentLayer = that.map.getLayer("Project");
        currentLayer.applyEdits([currentProjectGraphic], null, null);
    });
    // all results processing done here - can run any final code here
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I applied the easier method by Sam Onela and it worked, but I appreciate you answer and I will find a time to test it and learn it. Thanks!

Comment: @Atlas - It's kind of silly to run things sequentially when they can run in parallel.  It just makes things take longer to finish.

Comment: But the quick process requires the result from the slow process. It will get no value then. That's why I have to run it one after another.

Comment: @Atlas - I don't know what that means "quick process requires the result from the slow process".  I don't see different processes in your quesetion. 
 This code gathers all the results and then lets you process them in order and then do anything else you want when they are all done.

Comment: Oh I mean my previous wrong code. The loop runs faster than the inside part, so it got no result. I haven't got time to test yours but I think it works better than Sam's. I will try later if I have time. Thanks~