# Looping with multiple API calls - Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of users who I'll loop through to get their twitch information. I have two api calls: get_channel_info1 and get_status_info1. get_channel_info1 gets the name and logo and check if accounts exist. Then depending on the account status, I want to make a second api to see if they are online or not. I created get_info to make sequential calls for one user, but now I want to use this method in a loop.

I guessing the loop doesn't isn't waiting for the api calls in the get_info to finish before continuing through the loop. I'm not sure how to overcome this problem. Could anyone help me with this?

```
function get_channel_info1(user) {
  console.log(user);
  return $.getJSON("https://" + user,function(data) {
    if (data.status == null) {
      twitch_channel.display_name = data.display_name;
      twitch_channel.logo = data.logo;
      twtich_channel.status = 200;
    } else if (data.status == 404) {
      twitch_channel.display_name = "User " + user + " doesn't exist";
      twitch_channel.logo = "#";
      twitch_channel.status = 404;
    }
  })
}

function get_status_info1(user) {
    console.log("getting the status of " + user)
    console.log(user)
    return $.getJSON("https://" + user.display_name, function(data) {
        if (data.stream != null) {
          twitch_channel.status_title = data.stream.channel.status;
          twitch_channel.status = "Online";
        } else{
          twitch_channel.status_title = "Null";
          twitch_channel.status = "Offline";
        }
      })
}

function get_info(user) {
  twitch_channel = {};
  $.when(get_channel_info1(user)).then(function() { return get_status_info1(twitch_channel, user)} )
   .then( function() { console.log(twitch_channel })
};

for (var i = 0; i < twitch_list.length; i++) {
  console.log("in the for loop, calling " + twitch_list[i])
  get_info(twitch_list[i]);
}
```

Comment: A problem I see is that you're putting 2 parameters into `get_status_info1`, while your function takes only 1 parameter. It doesn't look like you have any glaring async issues, but you're not passing the `user` into the function.

Comment: Read up on [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)s and [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)s. Then you might look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42986752/215552).